# Can I get boxplot notches in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Yes, I know it's been around, I've also found Hadley's answer on google groups that there is no notches yet for `ggplot2` boxplots. So my question is twofold: Has this changed (there's a native implementation of notches already) and if not is there something one could do about it.

I mean I do not need the notch optic, representing the confidence bounds by some shaded area that is suitably placed in another layer over the boxplot, would look nice, too.

Also added a screenshot because I heard a graphics question is never complete without the graphic 
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**
In addition to the options detailed below, version 0.9.0 of **ggplot2** includes this feature in `geom_boxplot`. Examining `?geom_boxplot` reveals a `notch` and `notchwidth` argument:

```
+ geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, notchwidth = 0.5)
```

---

Not elegant graphics but here is an example:

```
# confidence interval calculated by `boxplot.stats`
f <- function(x) {
    ans <- boxplot.stats(x)
    data.frame(ymin = ans$conf[1], ymax = ans$conf[2])
}

# overlay plot (upper panel below)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom = "linerange", colour = "skyblue", size = 5)
p

# base graphics (lower panel below)
boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, notch = TRUE)
```

you can change the apparence of CI bar by tweaking the arguments of `stat_summary`.

[image] [image]

crossbar version:

```
f <- function(x) {
  ans <- boxplot.stats(x)
  data.frame(ymin = ans$conf[1], ymax = ans$conf[2], y = ans$stats[3])
}

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.8) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom = "crossbar", 
    colour = NA, fill = "skyblue", width = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Not bad! By widening the skyblue rectangle and maybe adding a little transparency to it, would be basically perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: hmm, I realize the fixed size is a problem when scaling the plot. Can't we have a more dynamic size?

Comment: Updated. I put the crossbar version.

Comment: What are the confidence intervals shown here? 90 or 95% for example.

Comment: So helpful! Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

It may be interesting that on the [ggplot2-dev mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2-dev?lnk=srg) a post concerning [notched box plots](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2-dev/browse_thread/thread/3e9f3eaa64779922) has been posted.

You can find the development page on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2). The package may be installed via:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("ggplot2")
```