# ggplot2 boxplot: horizontal bar at median?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to make a ggplot2 boxplot more meaningful by adding a thick bar at the median (so that if the median is equal to either of the lower or upper quartiles, it can be detected to which it is equal). I came across a recent post of Kohske:
[Can I get boxplot notches in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134699/can-i-get-boxplot-notches-in-ggplot2)
but I didn't know how to give the "crossbar" a "height". Then I tried 
to use a rectangle but it didn't work either. Here is a minimal example:

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(reshape2) 
require(plyr) 
set.seed(1) 
## parameters 
p1 <- c(5, 20, 100) 
p2 <- c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5") 
p3 <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5") 
N <- 1000 
## lengths 
l1 <- length(p1) 
l2 <- length(p2) 
l3 <- length(p3) 
## build result array containing the measurements 
arr <- array(rep(NA, l1*l2*l3*N), dim=c(l1, l2, l3, N), 
         dimnames=list( 
         p1=p1, 
         p2=p2, 
         p3=p3, 
         N=1:N)) 
for(i in 1:l1){ 
    for(j in 1:l2){ 
        for(k in 1:l3){ 
            arr[i,j,k,] <- i+j+k+runif(N, min=-4, max=4) 
        } 
    } 
} 

arr <- arr + rexp(3*5*5*N) 
## create molten data 
mdf <- melt(arr, formula = . ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + N) # create molten data frame 
## confidence interval calculated by `boxplot.stats` 
f <- function(x){ 
    ans <- boxplot.stats(x) 
    data.frame(x=x, y=ans$stats[3], ymin=ans$conf[1], ymax=ans$conf[2]) 
} 

## (my poor) trial 
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=p3, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=1) + 
stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="rectangle", colour=NA, fill="black", 
xmin=x-0.36, xmax=x+0.36, ymin=max(y-0.2, ymin), ymax=min(y+0.2, 
ymax)) + facet_grid(p2 ~ p1, scales = "free_y") 


**SOLUTION** (after the discussion with Kohske below):
f <- function(x, height){
    ans <- median(x)
    data.frame(y=ans, ymin=ans-height/2, ymax=ans+height/2)
}
p <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x=p3, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=1) +
stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="crossbar", height=0.5, colour=NA,
         fill="black", width=0.78) +
facet_grid(p2 ~ p1, scales = "free_y")
pdf()
print(p)
dev.off()

**UPDATE** Hmmm... it's not that trivial. The following example shows that the "height" of the crossbar should be adapted to the y-axis scale, otherwise it might be overseen.

require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
set.seed(1)
## parameters
p1 <- c(5, 20, 100)
p2 <- c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5")
p3 <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5")
N <- 1000
## lengths
l1 <- length(p1)
l2 <- length(p2)
l3 <- length(p3)
## build result array containing the measurements
arr <- array(rep(NA, l1*l2*l3*N), dim=c(l1, l2, l3, N),
     dimnames=list(
     p1=p1,
     p2=p2,
     p3=p3,
     N=1:N))
for(i in 1:l1){
    for(j in 1:l2){
        for(k in 1:l3){
            arr[i,j,k,] <- i+j^4+k+runif(N, min=-4, max=4)
        }
    } 
}
arr <- arr + rexp(3*5*5*N)
arr[1,2,5,] <- arr[1,2,5,]+30
arr[1,5,3,] <- arr[1,5,3,]+100

## create molten data
mdf <- melt(arr, formula = . ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + N) # create molten data frame

f <- function(x, height){
    ans <- median(x)
    data.frame(y=ans, ymin=ans-height/2, ymax=ans+height/2)
}

## plot
p <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x=p3, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=1) +
stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="crossbar", height=0.7, colour=NA,
         fill="black", width=0.78) +
facet_grid(p2 ~ p1, scales = "free_y")
pdf()
print(p)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Not that minimal, but more importantly, it's not reproducible.  Try to run this in a clean session - the value of `x` is not found.

Comment: It *is* reproducible. I should have said this: It is not working (exactly due to this reason). If it was working, I wouldn't have asked :-)

Comment: I particularly don't understand why x is not found since I specifically return it in the data.frame in the function f...

Comment: the reason way you get the error is that you don't use `mapping=aes(...)`. try `stat_summary(..., mapping = aes(xmin = x-0.36, ...))`. but I don't think this will solve your question.

Comment: and also, the horizontal line you see in the boxplot is just median.

Comment: Hi Kohske, thanks for helping. I know it's just the median. My goal is to make the median more visible by making the line "broader". The problem with the default is that if you have data where the median is equal to the upper quartile, you can't determine whether it is equal to the upper or the lower quartile because the bar is of the same size as the one for the quartiles. With a broader bar, one is able to detect the difference. This was also introduced in base graphics' boxplot some time ago.

Comment: Okay, but now I get "Error: no geom called rectangle"... hmmm.. what's a geom one could use here? I couldn't find a "height" argument for crossbar.


    `ggplot(mdf, aes(x=p3, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=1) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="rectangle", colour=NA,     fill="black",
    mapping=aes(xmin=x-0.36, xmax=x+0.36, ymin=max(y-0.2, ymin),     ymax=min(y+0.2,
    ymax))) + facet_grid(p2 ~ p1, scales = "free_y")`

Comment: Then, could you please provide an example of the base graphics version of the plot? A picture is worth a thousand words :)

Comment: I put the answer, but I'm happy if you will provide an example of base graphic version. It will be also useful for other readers.

Comment: A base-boxplot of the above is quite difficult (that's why I use ggplot2 :-) ), but you can perfectly see what I mean by looking at  `boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays)` [that's the first example in ?boxplot]. You can clearly see that the median is represented by a thicker horizontal line than the lower and upper quartiles (or the whole box if you want). If you look at group "D" you see that in this case the median is equal to the upper quartile. This would not be distinguishable from the case where the median is equal to the lower quartile if the median did not have a thicker line.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I think it will be useful option if the line style of median can be modified.

Answer (score 7):

here is an example:

```
f <- function(x, height) {
 ans <- median(x)
 data.frame(ymin = ans-height/2, ymax = ans+height/2, y = ans)
}

df <- data.frame(x=gl(2,6), y=c(1,1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3,3))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_boxplot() + 
 stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom = "crossbar", height = 0.1,
  colour = NA, fill = "skyblue", width = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

if you just want to change the apparence, then here is a quick hack, I don't recommend though,

```
df <- data.frame(x=gl(2,6), y=c(c(1,1,1,1,3,3), c(1,1,3,3,3,3)*10))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(x~.)

gs <- grid.gget("geom_boxplot", grep = T)
if (inherits(gs, "grob")) gs <- list(gs)
gss <- llply(gs, function(g) g$children[[length(g$children)]])

l_ply(gss, function(g) grid.edit(g$name, grep=T, just = c("left", "center"), height = unit(0.05, "native"), gp = gpar(fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.5, col = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is funny, I actually tried this before I posted the question, but a "height" wasn't found for a crossbar... Thanks! The `width` should be 0.78, otherwise the bar is broader than the box. Furthermore, the `height` must depend on the actual output. I had to choose a larger height in the above posted solution in order to make the medians visible.

Comment: the `height` is passed to `f`, not to crossbar. I modified the `f` so that it draws median with the specified `height`.

Comment: How exactly can I get the updated version? I always have trouble with installing from a github repository... Is it simply `install_github("ggplot2")` or do I have to specify a branch...?

Comment: Another point: I would recommend to use `outlier.shape=1` as default. The reason is that once you have a couple of outliers, you don't see anything anymore (for example, the information of how many points are drawn more or less on top of each other is not visible anymore [in contrast to `outlier.shape=1` which produces non-filled circles])

Comment: A final comment on boxplots: I have always been wondering why ggplot2 does not give whiskers by default. The median and the quartiles are shown with horizontal lines. It would be much easier for the eye to detect the endpoints of the whiskers if they where indicated by horizontal lines, too (?) Is there a reason for that? From a typographic point-of-view, the "classical" way would be preferable.

Comment: Dear Kohske, please not the "UPDATE" above. As you can see, specifying a fixed (i.e., row-col-independent) height might be unsuitable. In row 2 and row 5, the bars are not thick enough whereas in row one they are rather a bit too thick... Do you know a solution to that?

Comment: @MariusHofert the answer was updated. I don't recommend this way. Not sure to work in the future version. Also, I recommend you to provide *minimal* example with *small* dataset.